# Getting the teaser text without overriding global variables

Tags: functions, theme-development, themes, globals

I am trying to make a WordPress theme, following the [Wordpress Coding Standards - WPCS](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards). In functions.php, I have a function to get only the teaser (text above the read more-tag). The function works, however I get an error from Code Sniffer that `Overriding WordPress globals is prohibited`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this, while following the Coding Standards would be great!

My code:

```
global $more;
$more_saved = $more;

// Sets $more to not showing the content after the more tag.
$more = 0;
echo esc_html( get_the_content( '', false ) );

// Restores $more.
$more = $more_saved;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_extended() saved me! The returned array has 'main' and 'extended' keys. Main has the text before the `<!--more-->`. The 'extended' key has the content after the `<!--more-->` comment.

```
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );
$content_parts = get_extended( $content );
echo esc_html( strip_tags( $content_parts['main'] ) );
```